# Convert a datetime to another format using php

Tags: php, datetime

I am trying to convert the following datetime string into another format of date & time.

Thu Dec 15 10:05:14 +0000 2016

To

15 Dec

My code is

```
created_at = 'Thu Dec 15 10:05:14 +0000 2016';
$new_dt = date_format(strtotime($created_at),'jS F');
```

But it displays nothing.Any suggestion is highly appreciated.

Comment: $created_at = 'Thu Dec 15 10:05:14 +0000 2016';
$new_dt = date_format(strtotime($created_at),'jS F'); print $new_dt;

Comment: @Goikiu Thanks but just wondering if there is anything new.

Comment: @Goikiu added a row: `print $new_dt;` Since you said it displays nothing, you aren't really printing anything out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`date_format()` is an alias for `DateTime::format()`, and it accepts `DateTimeInterface` instances (e.g. `DateTime` *objects*), not raw UNIX timestamps.

Also, relying on "magic" functions like `strtotime()` is bad in general.

What you need is the following:

```
$new_dt = DateTime::createFromFormat('D M d H:i:s O Y', $created_at)
          ->format('jS F');
```

Or if you really insist on using the procedural-style functions:

```
$new_dt = date_format(
    date_create_from_format('D M d H:i:s O Y', $created_at),
    'jS F'
);
```